# phpinfo() file instead of sites index

Tags: apache, indexing, php

**phpinfo() file showing instead of all sites index**, after server software upgrade. (example site on this server: sms4.pro)
**There are many websites in this server, and ALL websites have this phpinfo instead of thier index..** 
Websites files is exists, FTP is accessible, databases/phpmyadmin is OK, but for unknown reasons displayed phpinfo instead of sites content.

I have already tried a variety of solutions, but still can not find a way how to fix it.
Maybe you have encountered a similar problem? Please help ..

My server is apache, debian 8, PHP Version 5.6.30-0+deb8u1

Answer (score 0):

Check your web root folder, i.e. /var/www in most cases, and check all files that are named index.* where * is any file extension. From the looks of it one of these files is calling phpinfo() and it is being used as your index file. Either modify this file to reflect what you want the index page to be or remove it if it is overriding another index file. You can also specify what you want your index file to be by modifying the Apache config file's DirectoryIndex directive. More info here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Answer (score 0):

If you've just done an update and this happened it is possible that your Apache configurations have been lost (or moved) and all requests to the server, regardless of which domain it comes from, is just being served what is in the `/var/www/` folder (which might be a file with just `phpinfo();` in it).

Depending on which version of Apache you've updated from, you might need to change the extension of the files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` (which are what point to the configurations for the different websites running on the server) to end in `.conf`

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ has sites configuration files with ending .vhost and 000-default.conf with content: <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Comment: You'll probably find that `/var/www/html/` contains an `index.php` file that contains `phpinfo();` and is the only configuration being loaded. Try rename one of your *.vhost files to *.vhost.conf and see if that website starts working correctly. Don't forget to reload your Apache configuration after you make the change.

Comment: unfortunately /var/www/html/ contains only index.html - Apache2 Debian Default Page

Comment: Any luck with renaming one of your confirmation files?

Comment: There are about 100 vhost files. If I renaming one, script creates new  file with the same  name (I'm using ISPconfig control panel..)

Comment: Found this: http://www.ceus-now.com/ubuntu-server-upgrade-to-14-04-2-lts-and-ispconfig-upgrade-to-3-0-5-4p5-websites-not-working/. The cause of problem appears to be the same but it has a potential solution for ISPConfig.